# Is Unique: Implement an algorithm to determine if a string has all unique characters

Tags: algorithm

Ch01_Q01: **1.1 Is Unique: Implement an algorithm to determine if a string
has all unique characters.**

Here we are assuming, it is an ASCII string

From, Cracking the Coding Interview, 6th Edition
Chapter 1. Arrays and Strings

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Hint: Use a Hashmap.

Comment: They have a github with solutions. But some ideas off the top of my head are to add them to a set or some other data type that will easily allow you to leverage it's properties to detect a duplicate. If you were limited in memory, you could do an in-place sort and then walk the sorted data linearly and compare neighbors for uniqueness. https://github.com/careercup/CtCI-6th-Edition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private static boolean isStringUnique(String s) {
    // ASCII has only 128 unique characters
    if (s.length() > 128) {
        return false;
    }

    int[] aCharSet = new int[128];

    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        int value = s.charAt(i);
        if(aCharSet[value] > 0) {
            return false;
        } else {
            aCharSet[value]++;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Look at the complete solution here: https://github.com/doshidev/CrackingTheCodingInterview/blob/master/Ch01ArrayAndStrings/src/IsUnique.java

Answer (score 0):

Here a few more implementations you may find helpful. The first is in C++ and the rest are in python. You also got some pretty good hints above. In the first Python implementation you will see a set. A set is an unordered collection that does not contain duplicate elements. In other words, a set contains all unique values.

```
bool is_unique(const std::string& s) {
  if (s.size() > 128)
    return false;

  std::array<bool, 128> seen;
  seen.fill(false);

  for (char n : s) {
    char current = n;
    if (seen[current]) {
      return false;
    } else {
      seen[current] = true;
    }
  }
  return true;
}


def is_unique(string):
    if len(string) == len(set(string)):
        return True
    else:
        return False


def _is_unique(string):
    if len(string) > 128:
        return False

    seen = [False]*128

    for elem in string:
        current = string.index(elem)
        if seen[current]:
            return False
        else:
            seen[current] = True
    return True


def final_is_unique(str):
    if len(str) > 128:
        return False

    seen = [False]*128

    for elem in str:
        current = ord(elem)
        if seen[current]:
            return False
        else:
            seen[current] = True
    return True
```